# Overlay image button is invisible (Android)

Tags: android, layout, android-camera

I would like to overlay an image button on top of the camera preview in my camera app, so that the camera preview can take up the entire screen and the user can still take pictures.

My activity_camera.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_photo"
            android:id="@+id/take_photoimageButton"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way I can edit the layout so that the button is visible while the camera is previewing?

EDIT - 
Here is my preview class:

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;

    Preview(Context context, Camera inCamera) {
        super(context);
        camera = inCamera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void OLDsurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
       // camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

//            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
//
//                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
//                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
//                    try {
//                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
//                                "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
//                        outStream.write(data);
//                        outStream.close();
//                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
//                                + data.length);
//                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    } catch (IOException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    } finally {
//                    }
//                    Preview.this.invalidate();
//                }
//            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            camera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void OLDsurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        //parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        //camera.setParameters(parameters);
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(0);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width, cs.height);
        //parameters.setRotation(90);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG, "draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your ```SurfaceView``` for the camera preview? a.k.a the camera related layouts?

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you create a SurfaceView for the preview in code and add it to the preview FrameLayout using addView(), change your layout to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <!-- Empty layout where SurfaceView will be placed in code-->

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_photo"
            android:id="@+id/take_photoimageButton"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In terms of z-order, views declared later in your layout are drawn on top of those declared earlier, and views added in code are drawn on top as if they had been added to the end of the layout (unless you specify an index). Placing an empty layout to add the SurfaceView to allows it to be drawn under the ImageButton.

Alternatively you could try calling addView() with an index of 0, however the question asked how to achieve this in the layout XML.

Unless you need to use the LinearLayout for some other reason, you can get rid of it and make the outer FrameLayout the top-level ViewGroup.